# How to collapse toolbar in a layout with DrawerLayout, Toolbar and ViewPager with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

Although there are lots of questions regarding this subject, none of them seemed to help me (I've tried most of what was adiviced but still can't make it work). My layout is bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

                <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    app:stl_defaultTabTextAllCaps="true"
                    app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="#000"
                    app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="0dip"
                    app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="0dp"
                    app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="14sp"
                    app:stl_distributeEvenly="true"
                    app:stl_drawDecorationAfterTab="true"
                    app:stl_indicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:stl_indicatorGravity="bottom"
                    app:stl_indicatorInFront="false"
                    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
                    app:stl_indicatorThickness="2dp"
                    app:stl_overlineThickness="0dp"
                    app:stl_titleOffset="24dp"
                    app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/rsc_homepage_drawer_layout_content"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_itens" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Each fragment has one RecyclerView. What is the problem? When I scroll the RecyclerView nothing happens. If I scroll the toolbar then it hides, leaving the RecyclerView in its original position. Any help is appreciated!

## UPDATE

Below are all my fragments:

## Fragment 1

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView/>
                <TextView />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <TextView/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" />
```

## Fragment 2

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null">

....

<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/not_results_found_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:alpha="0.95"
                android:elevation="4dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/not_results_found"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/rsc_search_friends_no_results_founds"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textH3"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/result"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/not_results_found_wrapper"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:overScrollMode="never" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

## Fragment 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/msg_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dip"
        android:alpha="0.95"
        android:elevation="4dip"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/results_not_found"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="15dip"
            android:text="@string/frag_chats_no_chat_use"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textH2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

## Fragment 4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/games"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_wrapper"
        android:overScrollMode="never"/>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_white_24dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/games"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from `ViewPager` and it to each parent of your Fragment (parent view of RecyclerView).

Comment: Same thing. What I've just realized is that two of my fragments has by parent component a ScrollView and another CoordinatorLayout. Is that a problem?

Comment: yes, scroll view will restrict the collapsing of toolbar. so either provide your recyclerview a linear or relative layout with `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` or no parent at all and recycler view with above `layout_behaviour` flag.

Comment: For testing purposes I've replaced the ScrollView for a RelativeLayout and the second CoordinatorLayout for a FrameLayout, still having the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `RecyclerView` in `NestedScrollView`.

Something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly nothing has changed